# React Native two time taps required for onPress event inside scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, tap, onpress

I'm using TextInput inside ScrollView and KeyboardAvoidingView but it require two time taps for submit text when keyboard is open.
for soluation i'm add **keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"** but it not working.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}}>
            <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" 
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    flexGrow : 1,
                    justifyContent : 'center',
                    alignItems:'center'}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'green', width:'100%', borderRadius:8, overflow:'hidden'}}>
                    <TextInput style={{margin:10}}/>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {alert('alert')}}>
                        <Text>Submit</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

> How to fire on press event on single tap?

Comment: i was use this component to another page scrollview so it's not working after add "keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"" on that super scrollview issue solved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid having to click TouchableOpacity twice to trigger onPress event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264910/how-to-avoid-having-to-click-touchableopacity-twice-to-trigger-onpress-event)

Answer (score 6):

Use `"handled"` instead of `"always"`.
`keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"`

Comment: It works (keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" with a "d" as you wrote the first time)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a onPress method of TouchableOpacity component something like this

```
 <TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => alert('Clicked)}>
      <Text>Submit</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```